# GroupBy on certain columns in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following table called TransportBooking with data in the following columns :

```
PrintBatchNo    Count    Created            AdditionalInfo    C_Country_ID
1                10    08-nov-17 13:48:00      test1               100
1                10    08-nov-17 13:48:00      test2               100
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42      test3               101
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42      test4               101
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42      test5               102
```

My sql is :

```
SELECT q1.printbatchno,
       q1.count,
       Min (q2.created),
       q2.ainfo,
       q2.countryid
FROM  (SELECT Count(tb.printbatchno) AS Count,
              tb.printbatchno
       FROM   transportbooking tb
       WHERE  tb.printbatchno IS NOT NULL
              AND tb.printbatchno > 0
       GROUP  BY tb.printbatchno)q1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT tb.printbatchno,
                         To_char(tb.created, 'dd-mon-yy  hh24:mi:ss')       AS Created,
                         tb.additional_info AS ainfo,
                         tb.c_country_id    AS countryid
                  FROM   transportbooking tb
                  WHERE  tb.printbatchno IS NOT NULL
                         AND tb.printbatchno > 0)q2
              ON q2.printbatchno = q1.printbatchno
GROUP  BY q1.printbatchno,
          q1.count,
          q2.created,
          q2.countryid,
          q2.ainfo
ORDER  BY q2.created;
```

The sql above gives me the following result :

```
 PrintBatchNo    Count    MIN(q2.Created)          Ainfo     CountryID
1                10    08-nov-17 13:48:00          test1        100
1                10    08-nov-17 13:48:00          test2        100
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42          test3        101
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42          test4        101
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42          test5        102
```

I want it to appear like this :

```
PrintBatchNo    Count    Created            AdditionalInfo    C_Country_ID
1                10    08-nov-17 13:48:00      test1               100
2                25    08-nov-17 19:02:42      test3               101
```

So, I want that the sql show only 1 row per printbatchno and should show the row with the minimum created date for that printbatchno. Also, it should show the AdditionalInfo and the C_Country_ID columns.

Can somebody tell me whats going wrong for me?

Thanks

Comment: use `distinct`  I guess

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would use window functions:

```
select tb.*
from (select tb.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PrintBatchNo order by Created) as seqnum
      from transportbooking tb
     ) tb
where seqnum = 1;
```